# escape quote with paste in r

Tags: r, escaping, paste

I've tried to follow other related question here, and the answer is not working for me, so I apologize for what is likely a duplicate question. I'm not finding other answers work for me.

I have 2 strings:

```
numbers = 1:12
month = month.name
```

I want to paste together to get the following, having quotes around the number, and quotes around the month, with an equal sign between:

```
""1" = "January"", ""2" = "February"", etc.
```

But 
`paste(numbers, month, sep = '" = "')`
and
`paste(numbers, month, sep = '\" = \"')`

both give result:

`"1\" = \"January"   "2\" = \"February"...etc.`

How do I get rid of the \?

Comment: The `\"` you are seeing in the output in your R console are just literal double quotes, escaped by backslash so as to distinguish them from the double quotes which denote the literal string.  Your code may already be working.

Comment: To further clarify Tim's comment, it won't be there when you actually print it e.g. as a data frame, or with `cat`. Compare `cat(paste('"', numbers, '" = "', month, '"'))` with and without `cat`. It also doesn't show up in data frames, e.g. `data.frame( a = paste('"', numbers, '" = "', month, '"'))`